# Local website redirect

Tags: redirect, wamp, hosts

I have a website running on let's say: www.example.com

On my local WAMP installation, I have the same website Cloned with GIT. The address is localhost/www.example.com

Drupal is installed, and always goes to localhost/ instead of localhost/www.example.com/

Is there a way to make a local 'redirect' from 'example' to 'localhost/www.example.com/'?
A bit like localhost is handled in the hosts file...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite on apache can help you. you can write a rule to redirect localhost/example to localhost/www.example.com/

these links can get you started.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 0):

After hours of looking for a sollution, I found an answer!

User virtualHosts
http://cesaric.com/?p=255

```
Now 'http://example' is virtualhost for 'http://localhost/www.example.com/'
```

Very nice :)